# Will water be superconducting if add enough pressure?

Tags: experimental-physics, superconductivity

Recently, room temperature superconductor has draw a lot of attention. Previous studies haven shown $H_2S$ is superconducting near room temperature given enough pressure.

[image]

I wonder if water $H_2O$ will be superconducting if suppress it hard enough. Has anyone tried? If not, why?

Comment: Is ice a metallic conductor at any known pressure?

Comment: Re to self: I guess the answer is yes! https://news.cornell.edu/stories/2012/01/scientists-predict-out-world-kind-ice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [theoretical prediction](https://doi.org/10.1002/cphc.202000582) that pure $\mathrm{H_2O}$ will become a superconductor at pressures above $5$ TPa with a critical temperature of $\mathrm{T_c=}1.8\,\mathrm{K}$.
Such pressures are currently [not experimentally achievable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_anvil_cell), but
there is [another prediction](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-017-07145-4) that a few percent doping with nitrogen would make water a superconductor with $\mathrm{T_c \sim}60\,\mathrm{K}$ at an accessible pressure of only $\mathrm{0.15\,TPa}$. Unfortunately, nitrogen and water don't seem to mix well under these conditions. [An experimental study](https://doi.org/10.1063/5.0052315) could find no sign of ice doping by nitrogen at high pressures up to $\mathrm{0.14\,TPa}$.

Comment: It is a very hard experiment and the hope seems small